# Bootstrap dropdown not working on ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get bootstrap dropdown to work, bootstrap displays correctly but dropdown action is not working, I suspect it has something to do with jquery, but jquery is working just fine.

./Gemfile

```
gem "bootstrap", "~> 4.4"    
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 4.3"
```

./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

./app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

On my browser's console calling

```
$('.dropdown-toggle')
```

works just fine, however when calling

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function at <anonymous>:1:23`

Here is the html copied from [Bootstrap's navbar example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Edit:

Popper.js is being included correctly, I've tested this by removing the manual import, I think the issue is when including jquery and bootstrap, since once I remove one of those manual imports the dropdown breaks (without changing the view)

Comment: Can you share the html?

Comment: @Seyon Just added it

Comment: When you try including the javascripts explicitly in your html through script src commands(see top part of: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) does it work?

Comment: @Seyon It works as expected, aren't those javascripts added on application.js?

Comment: Try to define jquery before bootstrap in your application.js

Comment: @Archer defining jquery before bootstrap didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/), bootstrap 4 dropdowns are built on a third party library, popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Maybe you don't have popper.js, or it does not work for some reason.

Comment: I think this is the closest to an answer, however including popper in my application.js didn't seem to work. Including the javascripts explicitly as @Seyon suggested did work, but I don't think It works, as it avoids doesn't use rails asset pipeline.

Comment: Check your installation. For example [here](https://www.timdisab.com/installing-bootstrap-4-on-rails-6/) is a reasonable-looking tutorial on installing Bootstrap 4 to Rails 6 with Webpacker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer is relevant now. But I was able to fix the drop-down issue by making changes in application.html.erb file.

Earlier it was like this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Then I changed it to this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `data-target="dropdown-menu"` section after `data-target="dropdown"`.